# How to install SoPlex solver in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, cmake, cmake-gui

I have downloaded SoPlex, but I don't know how to install it so that I can use it in Matlab. The installation says that CMake can be used to install it (https://soplex.zib.de/doc/html/INSTALL.php), but I don't know how to do it on Windows. I get error of configuration when I use CMake GUI probably because of not knowing which folder to choose. Is there any other way to download and use this software directly on Matlab?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we don't write guides and tutorials but help to resolve the **specific problems**. " I get error of configuration when I use CMake GUI probably because of not knowing which folder to choose." - Or because of one of other thousands reasons. Why do not describe **what exactly you are doing** and add to the question the **exact error message** you got? You may find useful that guide on writing questions on Stack Overflow: [ask].